# Angular injector mod error in Karma

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Getting the following error when I try and run karma and jasmine on a new project

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.37 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket RZqL_zkgcfP2w13UEtJj with id 40849718
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/nomod?p0=brainiacLms
  at /Users/christianeckenrodework/Sites/brainiac/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:25
```

This is my karma config

```
# // Karma configuration
# // Generated on Fri May 13 2016 16:53:01 GMT-0400 (EDT)

module.exports = (config) ->
  config.set
    basePath: './'
    frameworks: [ 'jasmine' ]
    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
      'web/app.coffee'
      'web/controllers/*.coffee'
      'test/**/*.coffee'
    ]
    exclude: []
    preprocessors: {
      'test/**/*.coffee': [ 'coffee' ]
      'web/**/*.coffee': [ 'coffee' ]
    }
    reporters: [ 'progress' ]
    port: 9876
    colors: true
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO
    autoWatch: true
    browsers: [ 'PhantomJS' ]
    singleRun: false
    concurrency: Infinity
```

As far as I can tell the issue seems to be that it cant find my app module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: the reason my test threw the injector error is because I wasn't including all of my applications dependencies in my karma.conf.js file

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to update your configuration file and use a `files` array like this:

```
files: [
  // bower:js
  'bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
      // more bower dependences here...
  // endbower
  'web/app.coffee',
  'web/**/*.coffee',
  'web/**/*.html',
  'test/**/*.coffee',
]
```

Just make sure include all your script and template files in your configuration file.

Also, if you're using `Grunt` or `Gulp` you can inject `bower_components` automatically in your Karma configuration.